# Bad name with saveas method

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to put the date in the name of a saved file.

The issue is that when i want to close the new file, it is either looking for a wrong name, something like "Nom10022021084CD09", or has given a list of 5 numbers instead of the actual date depending on the format (DDMMYYY or DD - MM - YYYY).

Here is a piece of my code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

    Dim Nom As String
    
    Nom = "Inter" & Format(Date, “DD - MM - YYYY”) & ".xlsm"    
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    
    Workbooks.Open ("S:\Backup\Archivage\Archivage_inter.xlsm")
    
    Workbooks("Archivage_inter").Worksheets("Feuil1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    Workbooks("Archivage_inter").SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\sm\Documents\test\" & Nom
        
    Workbooks("Nom").Close
End sub
```

Has anyone ever seen this problem ?

Comment: Remove the quotes around `"Nom"` in the last line. You'd also be better off using a workbook variable.

Comment: I tried without the quotes but I still have the same issue instead of today's date, it's written 44237.

Comment: You have the wrong type of quotes (curly) in your `Format` function - replace them with straight quotes - `"`

Comment: That was it, thank you.